# RIP Irrfan Khan

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Irrfan Khan was an Indian actor who left us today. With no backing, he climbed the success stairs based on raw talent. From a memorable supporting role in the Indian fantasy series *Chandrakanta* to a lead in tons of Bollywood films, he left a mark on his fans.

He also worked in Hollywood and British films such as *Life of Pi*, *The Amazing Spider-Man*, *Slumdog Millionaire*, *Inferno* and *Jurassic World*. His departure is a big loss for Bollywood as well as Hollywood and he will be remembered in the hearts of his fans forever.